# Prevent phone unlock by secondary google account

Tags: lock-screens, google-account

#### What I have done:

I have added multiple google accounts to my device.
Also did set screen pattern lock and pin as fallback.
Tried to give wrong pattern and selected unlocking by google account, I could use any active google account and it will remove both pattern and pin.

#### How I want it to behave:

I am lookin for some way to restrict unlocking/pin reset to individual selected google account while retaining keep/drive/mail/contacts/calendar etc, synchronization, is that even possible?

Comment: Although there is only one possible owner account, I'm not sure if what you said works unless you could use Android for Work

Comment: @TamoghnaChowdhury maybe I could use that, but I think it would only isolate paid corporate account but will not affect behavior of other free accounts. I've also found that AfW could be potentential source for other problems. Anyhow, it would not be general solution.